# Getting variables form text file, then setting a new variable

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I'm creating a code for the computers at work. I had to make an "Install" program. I didn't know how to do it properly but I found a way to do it.

When I "Install" the program on a other computer I have my USB-stick and copy it to the local disk at the computer.

Now I start the program for the first time at their computer and this code run's

and then I got an error here because Program is not yet divined:

Dim lMateriaalCertificaat As String = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Program & "Materialen&Certificaten.txt")

```
 Dim Pathproj As String = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
    Dim Pathfile As String = Pathproj.Replace("bin\Debug\", "Bestanden\Locatie.txt")

    Dim Program As String = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Pathfile)


    'Deze bestanden worden aangemaakt en er wordt automatisch een route ingezet.
    Dim lMateriaalCertificaat As String = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Program & "Materialen&Certificaten.txt")
        Dim lBibliotheek As String = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Program & "Bibliotheek.txt")
        Dim lExcel_autonummering As String = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Program & "Excelbestand autonummering.txt")
        Dim lLocatie_telbestanden As String = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Program & "Locatie telbestanden.txt")
        Dim lMapnamen As String = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Program & "Mapnamen.txt")
        Dim lOrderschijf As String = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Program & "Zoek schijf.txt")
```

Because when the form2_load I do this and then I wan't to divine that string.

```
Public Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim Locatie_05Kuipers As String
        If System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Pathfile) = "" Then
            'If System.IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\testing1\testing2\testing7\testing1\testing1\text.txt") = "" Then

            Locatie_05Kuipers = InputBox("Vul hier de Locatie waar je start bestanden moeten staan. Bijvoorbeeld: K:\Inventor\Instalprogram\ ")

            If System.IO.File.Exists(Pathfile) Then
                System.IO.File.Delete(Pathfile)
            End If

            Dim objStreamWriter As StreamWriter
            objStreamWriter = New StreamWriter(Pathfile)
            objStreamWriter.WriteLine(Locatie_05Kuipers & "\03 - Locaties")
            objStreamWriter.Close()

            ButtonInstal.Visible = True
            Exit Sub
        Else
        End If
```

So how or where do I need to put my strings?

Comment: Have you tried stepping through in a debugger?  Your first code block appears to show `Program` being defined.  After the line `Dim Program = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(PathFile)`, what does `Program` contain?

Comment: If those files are in the same location of your executable, use `Application.StartupPath` to get that location. `bin\Debug` is related to your Project's folder structure. This path is never explicitly used, referenced or otherwise *mentioned* anywhere in code, ever: that path doesn't exist. Use, e.g., `dim filePath = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "Bibliotheek.txt")`. -- The path in your `Program` (bad name) variable is wrong -- If you *install* your program in `Program Files`, you, probably, won't have write rights.

Comment: what I meant to say is that when Form2_loads I see if textfile `"Bestanden\Locatie.txt"` contains something. If not then I need to put a location in the text file, like `"C:\Installation map"`. But here the error comes because I do not have a location in it so the other `System.IO.File.ReadAllText` doesn't have the right route yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save a path in your settings, and every time you need it, you can create the file and put your data in it.

For example:

[image]

```
    Dim pathString As String = My.Settings.filePath
    Dim fullPath = Path.Combine(pathString, "Locatie.txt")
    If Not Directory.Exists(pathString) Then
        Directory.CreateDirectory(pathString)
        File.Create(fullPath)
    Else
        If Not File.Exists(pathString) Then
            File.Create(fullPath)
        Else
            Console.WriteLine($"File {fullPath}already exists.")
        End If
    End If
```